# Getting errors from web.config of parent application in my sub application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I have my main website's application on my server at `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`, which I can view at `http://www.mysite.com`

I've created another separate MVC web application, named `Supapp`, at `C:\inetpub\Supapp`. I'd like to set it up so that if I visit `http://www.mysite.com/Subdir`, it will run my `Subdir` app.

So I went into IIS, expanded my existing website, and added a new Application, pointing the root folder to `C:\inetpub\Supapp\`.

When I go to view `http://www.mysite.com/Subdir`, I get a compilation error:

> **Compiler Error Message: CS0246:** The type or namespace name 'MySite' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> **Source Error:**

```
Line 98:         <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
Line 99:         <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
Line 100:        <add namespace="MySite.HtmlHelpers" />
Line 101:      </namespaces>
Line 102:    </pages>
```

> **Source File:** c:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config    **Line:** 100

So for some reason, my sub application is getting an error from trying to load a namespace from the parent application.

Is there a way around this? The `Subdir` application is in a completely different directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

config files are  hierarchical, your sub web.config inherit things from your root .config. If you want certain parts to be ignred you can add `inheritInChildApplications="false"` attribute to tags you don't to be inherited.

For your case add `inheritInChildApplications="false"` to your aplication root `location`

```
   <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
   </location>
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't use this strategy, but with some research I found out I can also just add <clear /> at the top of the namespaces node.

Answer (score -2):

You will need to set up your sub application to be a web application in IIS.

Comment: I did. I went into IIS, expanded my existing website, and added a new Application, pointing the root folder to C:\inetpub\Supapp\